# How do I loop through dates in momentJS such that it will happen twice a month?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, luxon

I want to loop from Jan 1, 2022 until June 14, 2022 (or any given date) using momentJS or LuxonJS such that it happens twice in a given month. This is my code:

```
const frequency = [];
  for (var m = moment('2022-01-01'); m.isSameOrBefore('2022-06-14'); m.add(15, 'days')) {
    frequency.push({
      dueDate:  moment(m).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    });
  }
```

This is the Result:

```
frequency : [
  { dueDate: '2022-01-01' },
  { dueDate: '2022-01-16' },
  { dueDate: '2022-01-31' },
  { dueDate: '2022-02-15' },
  { dueDate: '2022-03-02' },
  { dueDate: '2022-03-17' },
  { dueDate: '2022-04-01' },
  { dueDate: '2022-04-16' },
  { dueDate: '2022-05-01' },
  { dueDate: '2022-05-16' },
  { dueDate: '2022-05-31' }
]
```

This is not my desired result because it happens thrice in January, once in February, and thrice in May.

I want the loop to consider the number of days in a month so that it loops twice each month.

My desired result is something similar to this but not specifically this as long as it loops twice in a month.

```
 desired : [
  { dueDate: '2022-01-01' },
  { dueDate: '2022-01-16' },
  { dueDate: '2022-02-01' },
  { dueDate: '2022-02-16' },
  { dueDate: '2022-03-01' },
  { dueDate: '2022-03-16' },
  { dueDate: '2022-04-01' },
  { dueDate: '2022-04-16' },
  { dueDate: '2022-05-01' },
  { dueDate: '2022-05-16' },
  { dueDate: '2022-06-01' },
]
```

Comment: instead of adding 15 days, add one month and push the 1st and 16th in the loop body?

Comment: Why do you insist using a library for that? This is easy with plain string manipulation.

Comment: `Array(6).fill().flatMap((e,i) => [{dueDate:`2022-0${i+1}-01`},{dueDate:`2022-0${i+1}-16`}])` somewhat hacky just an example with string manipuation

Comment: @trincot I would appreciate if you can help me out with some code please

Comment: Instead of always adding 15 days, try adding half of the total days in that month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.daysInMonth`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/days-in-month/) method to get the current amount of days in the current iterated month and add by the half amount of days.

```js
let frequency = [];
for (var m = moment('2022-01-01'); m.isSameOrBefore('2022-06-14'); m.add(1, 'month')) {
    frequency.push({
        dueDate:  moment(m).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    });
    frequency.push({
        dueDate:  moment(m).add(Math.floor(m.daysInMonth() / 2), 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    });
  }
```

Notice I also increment by month but push twice per month. It makes the intent much more clear.

Result:

```
[
  { "dueDate": "2022-01-01" },
  { "dueDate": "2022-01-16" },
  { "dueDate": "2022-02-01" },
  { "dueDate": "2022-02-15" },
  { "dueDate": "2022-03-01" },
  { "dueDate": "2022-03-16" },
  { "dueDate": "2022-04-01" },
  { "dueDate": "2022-04-16" },
  { "dueDate": "2022-05-01" },
  { "dueDate": "2022-05-16" },
  { "dueDate": "2022-06-01" },
  { "dueDate": "2022-06-16" }
]
```

Comment: If my start date is : 2022-01-15 and end date is 2022-05-15, There is only one day for February instead of the expected 2 and also, it includes 2022-05-30 when it is beyond the end date. What do I do?

Comment: I think the easiest approache would probably be generating the dates first and then slicing the array to fit the range ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a date library for that, as it can be done with string manipulation.

You could define a 1-to-1 mapping between dates and numbers, such that two consecutive numbers map to one month (either day 01 or day 16), and days of a month are mapped back accordingly.

Then it becomes a matter of iterating a range of numbers and map those back to date strings:

```js
function twicePerMonth(start, end) {
    const toNumber = s => (([y, m, d]) => 24*y+2*m+(d>1)+(d>16)-2)(s.split("-"));
    const toString = n => [~~(n / 24), ((n % 24) >> 1) + 1, (n % 2) * 15 + 1]
                          .join("-").replace(/\b\d\b/g, "0$&");

    start = toNumber(start);
    return Array.from({length: toNumber(end) - start}, (_, i) => ({
        dueDate: toString(start + i)
    }));
}

const result = twicePerMonth('2022-01-01',  '2022-06-13');
console.log(result);
```